# How i can filter a collection with a where like query on Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I have the following array:

```
$elements = collect([
     ['product_id' => 'prod-100', 'name' => 'Desk'],
     ['product_id' => 'prod-200', 'name' => 'Chair'],
 ]);
```

I need to filter by approximation, but just using the collection data, something like:

```
$elements->where('name', 'LIKE', 'De%')->values()->all();
```

Actually i can filter the data, but with a normal filter (where), this does not work for me because it find the exact coincidences. So, if i use a normal filter i have to say the exactly value to match:

```
$elements->where('name', 'Desk');
```

How i can made a query to the array data using something like a "Where LIKE" clausule?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `filter` function in collection and in closure use `preg_match` php function to check if it exist in name parameter like this:

```
$name='de';
$elements->filter(function ($item) use($name){
    return preg_match("/$name/",$item['name']);
});
```